# If a git branch is pushed to the remote and then deleted before it is merged, is it still part of the repository history?

Tags: git

A branch has been created and pushed to the remote, and a merge request has been opened for it.  At some point, it is decided to make significant enough changes that simply starting over in a new branch may be the easiest approach.

When the original branch is deleted from the remote, does any of its history linger in the remote repository, or is it (and any commits associated with it) completely removed from the remote?

Stated more succinctly, If I delete a remote branch without ever merging it to the main branch and someone does a git clone of the repo, will they end up downloading any sort of history information about that now-deleted branch, or would the clone by 'clean' w.r.t. this branch?

Comment: It's eligible to be deleted, but it might be recoverable if no cleanup has been done.

Comment: Thanks.  The concern is that what is in the branch is a large number of files (about 56M in total) that are better suited to something like a nexus download.  We're going to re-work them as such, but the question/concern is really this (I'll update the original question):

After the branch is deleted without being merged, will the next clone of the repo end up downloading any sort of history about the branch or the files in the branch?

Comment: Thanks, my goal is actually to completely delete it without any record of it having existed, so that behavior is a *good thing* in this case.

Comment: AFAIU it will be only *recoverable* on the **origin** repository (where the changes were made). And, of course, on any site where it was distributed (pushed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Stated more succinctly, If I delete a remote branch without ever merging it to the main branch and someone does a git clone of the repo, will they end up downloading any sort of history information about that now-deleted branch, or would the clone by 'clean' w.r.t. this branch?

It's really quite hard to say for certain.  In principle, someone cloning the repository *should* not get any objects that are not reachable from any of the reference-names they clone.  In practice, certain server side short-cuts might allow "data leakage".

To make this entirely concrete with examples, consider a repository *R* on some remote host you are calling `origin`.  *R* itself had just a `master` branch with commit hash `1234567...`.  You then did `git push origin newbranch`, adding some objects (including at least one new commit) to *R* and getting the Git at `origin` to add the new branch `newbranch` with hash ID `fedcba9...`.  Then you said: "oops, no, we don't want that" and did `git push origin :newbranch` to delete the *name* `newbranch`.

Provided there are no reflogs on the server, commit `fedcba9...` and its objects (and any earlier unreachable commits) are now eligible for garbage collection, as [Ryan noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920627/if-a-git-branch-is-pushed-to-the-remote-and-then-deleted-before-it-is-merged-is#comment74874504_43920627).  If these all *do* get garbage-collected, they are truly gone and cannot be observed by any normal means.<sup>1</sup>

If not, though, they are still in *R*, they just have no *name* by which they can be found.  Or, if the commit hash or hashes are saved in reflogs, they do have names, but these are reflog names, not a regular reference.  The `git clone` and `git fetch` processes do not obtain reflogs and hence cannot "see" the hash ID, but until the reflog entries expire, commit `fedcba9...` and related objects are not yet eligible for garbage collection.

Now we move on to the `git clone` process.  When you run:

```
git clone <options> <url>
```

you get your Git to call up another Git at the given URL.  Your Git then requests, from that Git, a list of all its normal (non-reflog) references.  For repo *R*, that's just `refs/heads/master = 1234567...`, since `refs/heads/newbranch` is gone.  Your Git then requests some (if `--depth` shallow clone) or all objects *reachable from* some or all of these names like `master`.  Since `fedcba9...` was never *reachable* from `master`, their Git *should* not send it.

There is, however, the option of doing a short-cut on the server.  The server has these "pack" files that contain every object that is not a loose object.  If there's just one pack file with everything, and no loose objects ... well: If the server could just send you that one "pack" file that has *everything*, why, that would save the server a lot of time and effort it would otherwise spend building a new, *customized* pack file that has just the objects you *want*.  If you've asked for all the refs, you must want *everything*.  There's just the one pack and no loose objects; that's *everything*.  There's no reason to spend all that time and effort building a *custom* pack, right? :-)

So, *if* the server does this, and *if* that one big pack file happens to have commit `fedcba9...` and its related objects in it, *then* (and only then) you would get a pack file that has `fedcba9...` and its related objects.  It would then be up to your Git to repack this and throw out the unwanted objects.

Does this ever happen in practice?  I have seen something like this in the past, but I can't say under exactly what circumstances it occurred.  Different versions of Git have had different code in them.  Big, heavily-used servers like GitHub (there are others as well) may have customized hacks in their Git implementations (many of these, such as pack bitmaps, have gone into regular Git over time).

The short version is that if any deleted data items are *sensitive* (passwords and the like), you should consider them compromised.  If you are just worried that there might be extra data downloaded, well, you have no real control over that: hope that the host with *R* either doesn't short-cut pack-building this way, or has done the appropriate garbage collection already.

---

<sup>1</sup>In other words, file system backups, snapshots, or, e.g., NSA-grade data recovery tools might still be able to find them, but Git won't.

Comment: Not really a comment about git so much as about a security issue touched on herein:  If you have pushed a commit with sensitive info like a password, then *even if you DO know* that your server won't short-cut the packing process on pulls, you still should consider the sensitive data compromised simply because you can't know if someone already pulled it before you caught the mistake.

Comment: This was purely about adding many large-ish vendor files and the effect that might have on clone time and not any sort of credentials (thankfully) so we're good on that front.

Sounds like even if it is a problem, it would be a temporarily problem and after some amount of time garbage collection would happen and a new pack would be created that doesn't have those commits, and new clones would be back to 'normal'.  I think I'm good.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the remote branch does not delete the commits; they might eventually be cleaned up by a `git gc` run.  If the remote is on a local shared drive or something of the sort, then it would be up to you if/when to run `gc` on it; and even then, a `gc` run can only remove a commit if *nothing* (including reflogs) can reach that commit.  If it's contained in a server (something like TFS) or hosted (by github or similar), then it depends on the options exposed by the server or hosting service, whether/how you have the option to run `gc`.

So the commits may stick around for a while, and may be accessible to someone who knows what they're looking for.

But you asked specifically about someone cloning/pulling.  The pack sent on pull or clone does not include anything that isn't reachable from some ref.  In this case even if there's a reflog entry it's not relevant.  If you delete the remote branch, and none of the commits in question have been tagged, merged, or had another branch created on them, then the commits should not be included in pull or close operations.

Comment: By the way, torek has a more detailed technical understanding, so if it's *very important* that a clone/pull not get those commits, you might want to consider the cases he points out where my above answer may not be accurate